# Translating methods from Scanner to BufferedReader

Tags: java.util.scanner, bufferedreader

I was doing a USACO contest recently. I had reached the correct algorithm for an answer, but I only got 7 test cases out of 10, with the remaining three showing up as "time limit exceeded". I searched up on GeeksforGeeks and javaTpoint on why this happens, and those two sites told me that either inefficient algorithms or the usage of `Scanner` instead of `BufferedReader`.

Throughout my Java experience (2 years), I have been using `Scanner` and am unfamiliar with anything else. Despite combing through several pages, I am unable to find a satisfactory answer to what methods in `Scanner` translate to which methods in `BufferedReader`, as I would like to use it moving forward. As I am unfamiliar with `BufferedReader`, I may be asking the wrong question. The methods I need are the `BufferedReader` equivalents to `nextLine()` and `nextInt()`. What are the use cases for each class, and how would I achieve the same function these methods do in `Scanner` using `BufferedReader`?

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods in BufferedReader to read from any data stream.

`int read(char[] cbuf, int off, int len)`

It is used for reading characters into a portion of an array.

`String readLine()`

It is used for reading a line of text.

BufferedReader is more useful when you want to read string type of data for that you can use `readLine()` method. For custom type like int, long etc preferred to use Scanner only. So there is no equivalents method for `nextInt()`, `nextLong()` in BufferedReader.